# createQueryBuilder doesn't work correctly

Tags: symfony4

I'm working on a personnel project (a e-commerce website) and I'm using ReactJS & Symfony. My issue is the following: I created a querybuilder in my file: ChaussureRepository.php to search every element in my table Chaussure where the name contains the word that I'm typing.

*ChaussureRepository.php*

```
/**
 * @return Chaussure[]
 */
public function findByNom($nom)
{
  $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->where('a.nom LIKE :name')
                ->setParameter('name', '%'.$nom.'%')
                ->getQuery();
  return $query->getResult();
}
```

*ChaussureController.php*

```
   * @Route("/recherche/{nom}", name="recherche_chaussure", methods={"get"})
   */
   public function index($nom) {
     $chaussures = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Chaussure::class)->findByNom($nom);
```

My Controller returns me an empty array. When I type a word that is in the name that I'm searching it doesn't work but when I type the full name it works. Someone can help me with my createQueryBuilder to make work LIKE %:name%.

Comment: Looks like you are getting the "standard" repository with the magic `findBy` methods instead of your custom one. Can you try injecting the repository instead of using `getRepository()`?

Comment: Sorry I'm french, can you explain me what do you mean "injectinf the repository instead of using getRepository()"? This is the only way I know to do that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be getting the default `Repository` instead of the custom one. The default implementation includes [magic `findBy` methods](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/8c259ea5cb632dbb57001b2262048ae7fa52b102/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L177) that allows to exact-match search any field of your entity out of the box, that's the behavior you are getting.

For the `getRepository()` call to return a custom repository, you must specify the repository class in your `Entity` metadata. Take a look to the second paragraph [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository). So you should check that your entity declaration includes the `repositoryClass`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ChaussureRepository")
 */
class Chaussure
{
// Other properties
}
```

Other option is to inject the custom repository directly in your controller. This is a bit cleaner since it makes the dependency explicit, but it might not be ideal if all your codebase uses the locator pattern as above.

```
use App\Repository\ChaussureRepository;

class ChaussureController
{
    public function index($nom, ChaussureRepository $repository) { 
        $chaussures = $repository->findByNom($nom);
        // ...
    }
}
```